# Parse a custom text file in Python

Tags: python, parsing

I have a text to be parsed, this is a concise form of the text.

```
apple {
    type=fruit
    varieties {
        color=red
        origin=usa
    }
}
```

the output should be as shown below

```
apple.type=fruit
apple.varieties.color=red
apple.varieties.origin=usa
```

So far the only thing I have come up with is a sort of breadth-first approach in python. But I cant figure out how to get all the children within.

```
progInput = """apple {
    type=fruit
    varieties {
        color=red
        origin=usa
    }
}
"""
progInputSplitToLines = progInput.split('\n')
childrenList = []
root = ""

def hasChildren():
    if "{" in progInputSplitToLines[0]:
        global root
        root = progInputSplitToLines[0].split(" ")[0]
    for e in progInputSplitToLines[1:]:
        if "=" in e:
            childrenList.append({e.split("=")[0].replace("    ", ""),e.split("=")[1].replace("    ", "")})
hasChildren()
```

PS: I looked into tree structures in Python and came across anytree (https://anytree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), do you think it would help in my case?

Would you please be able to help me out ? I'm not very good at parsing text. thanks a bunch in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your file is in HOCON format, you can try using the [`pyhocon`](https://github.com/chimpler/pyhocon) HOCON parser module to solve your problem.

**Install:** Either run `pip install pyhocon`, or download the github repo and perform a manual install with `python setup.py install`.

**Basic usage:**

```
from pyhocon import ConfigFactory

conf = ConfigFactory.parse_file('text.conf')

print(conf)
```

Which gives the following nested structure:

```
ConfigTree([('apple', ConfigTree([('type', 'fruit'), ('varieties', ConfigTree([('color', 'red'), ('origin', 'usa')]))]))])
```

[`ConfigTree`](https://configtree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is just a [`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), as seen in the [source code](https://pythonhosted.org/pyhocon/_modules/pyhocon/config_tree.html).

**UPDATE:**

To get your desired output, you can make your own recursive function to collect all paths:

```
from pyhocon import ConfigFactory
from pyhocon.config_tree import ConfigTree

def config_paths(config):
    for k, v in config.items():
        if isinstance(v, ConfigTree):
            for k1, v1 in config_paths(v):
                yield (k,) + k1, v1
        else:
            yield (k,), v

config = ConfigFactory.parse_file('text.conf')
for k, v in config_paths(config):
    print('%s=%s' % ('.'.join(k), v))
```

Which Outputs:

```
apple.type=fruit
apple.varieties.color=red
apple.varieties.origin=usa
```