# parsing the json kind of file to find out particular values using unix shell script/Python

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I would like to extract few lines of given  file using shell script. The problem is I have set of  files which need to parsed and extract data. The below examples explains my scenario: I am looking to extract only "source" and "destination" values from the given  files.

```
lists = [ 
{
name = "Account - UU ",
source = "1-account",
destination = "account-hhh",
other = "111111"
},
{
name = "Account - PP,
source = "2-account",
destination = "account-hhh12345",
other = "1212"
},
{
name = "Account - GG ",
source = "3-account",
destination = "account-gg567",
other = "44444"
},
{
name = "Account - QQ,
source = "4-account",
destination = "account-manager123456",
other = "23232323"
}
]
```

My expected output would be

```
source = "1-account" | destination = "account-hhh"
source = "2-account" | destination = "account-hhh12345"
source = "3-account" | destination = "account-gg567"
source = "4-account" | destination = "account-manager123456"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you've tried. I'm pretty sure a quick "google" would show you how to do this. Do you have or can you install a json parser such as `jq`?

Comment: It is not a valid json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can modify the list to a valid json format (as below) and `python` is your option,
please try:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

lists = [
{
"name" : "Account - UU",
"source" : "1-account",
"destination" : "account-hhh",
"other" : 111111
},
{
"name" : "Account - PP",
"source" : "2-account",
"destination" : "account-hhh12345",
"other" : 1212
},
{
"name" : "Account - GG",
"source" : "3-account",
"destination" : "account-gg567",
"other" : 44444
},
{
"name" : "Account - QQ",
"source" : "4-account",
"destination" : "account-manager123456",
"other" : 23232323
}
]

for i in lists:
    print('source = "%s" | destination = "%s"' % (i["source"], i["destination"]))
```

Output:

```
source = "1-account" | destination = "account-hhh"
source = "2-account" | destination = "account-hhh12345"
source = "3-account" | destination = "account-gg567"
source = "4-account" | destination = "account-manager123456"
```

**EDIT**

Assuming you have a HOCON file `file.conf` which looks like:

```
lists = [
{
name = "Account - UU",
source = "1-account",
destination = "account-hhh",
other = 111111
},
{
name = "Account - PP",
source = "2-account",
destination = "account-hhh12345",
other = 1212
},
{
name = "Account - GG",
source = "3-account",
destination = "account-gg567",
other = 44444
},
{
name = "Account - QQ",
source = "4-account",
destination = "account-manager123456",
other = 23232323
}
]
```

Then try to execute the python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from pyhocon import ConfigFactory

conf = ConfigFactory.parse_file('./file.conf')
for i in conf['lists']:
    print('source = "%s" | destination = "%s"' % (i['source'], i['destination']))
```

Output:

```
source = "1-account" | destination = "account-hhh"
source = "2-account" | destination = "account-hhh12345"
source = "3-account" | destination = "account-gg567"
source = "4-account" | destination = "account-manager123456"
```

**EDIT2**

If you want to parse multiple files in multiple directories recursively, save the following script as something like `myscript.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from pyhocon import ConfigFactory
import sys

conf = ConfigFactory.parse_file(sys.argv[1])
try:
    if type(conf['lists']) is list:
        for i in conf['lists']:
            print('source = "%s" | destination = "%s"' % (i['source'], i['destination']))
except Exception:
    pass
```

Then run:

```
find "$dir" -name "*.conf" -type f -exec python myscript.py {} \;
```

The command line above assumes the HOCON files have `.conf` extension and the variable `$dir` holds the top directory path of the conf files. Please modify them according to your environment.

**EDIT3**
The python script above may be altered by:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from pyhocon import ConfigFactory
import sys

conf = ConfigFactory.parse_file(sys.argv[1])
if 'lists' in conf.keys():
    for i in conf['lists']:
        print('source = "%s" | destination = "%s"' % (i['source'], i['destination']))
```

which will be a bit smarter.

Comment: Yea, I am looking for a solution if its available,e in python also.Basically am getting is it as conf file (Hocon). How do i call it as files rather than variables using python ?  basically i am getting these kind of sample files in a directory and i need to parse these files and find source and destination

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've updated my answer with an another version which reads the conf file as is, internally converts to json format, then outputs the same result. Would you please try it?

Comment: Thanks , as mentioned earlier my file is Hocon file. Looks like we need to use hocon parser - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53188635/parse-a-custom-text-file-in-python       Any idea how make it workable ?

Comment: Thank you for the info. Would you provide some example files? Or is it still okay to use the provided one as an example?

Comment: Thanks, sample file is exactly same as given in the question

Comment: Okay, thanks. Then how do I handle with the `corrupted` quotings I mentioned? Are they actually corrupted with the actual files? Anyway It's high time for me and let me resume tomorrow morning.

Comment: okay.. got it, I will update the file in question with double quotes

Comment: I've updated my answer to handle HOCON file. You will need to execute `pip install pyhocon` to install `pyhocon` package in advance.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I will try tonexecut in sometime.. ctually i have many filea in directrories as i mentiomed earlier. Inwoils like tonrecursively go through nd execut every file.. Is it smthg possible? Just checking

Comment: Okay, now I have updated my answer to find files recursively. If you feel comfortable with my answer, would you please accept it? Cheers.

Comment: Thank you.. I will run andnlet you know.. Will accept answer

Comment: Thank you.. it ran fine.. One small issue is - I have some conf files where i don't have source and destination , the python code is throwing some error. Do we have any method to avoid that conf files if it doesnt contain "lists" variable ?

Comment: Shall I skip (ignore) the conf files which do not contain `lists` variable?

Comment: Yes, we need to ignore the files which donot contains lists variable

Comment: All right. I have modified my python script to ignore the files which do not contain `lists`. How about then?

Comment: Thanks.. Will try and let you know... Really appreciate it